# Fetch data from xml file to textbox on selecting an item from combobox. How can this be achieved?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, combobox

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name>John</name>
    <salary>29000</salary>  
  </employee>

  <employee>
    <name>Harry</name>
    <salary>35000</salary>  
  </employee>
</employees>
```

Here i'm populating the employee names from xml file in the combobox

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
XmlNodeList colorList = doc.SelectNodes("employees/employee/name");
foreach (XmlNode Name in colorList)
{
    FeedComboBox.Items.Add(Name.InnerText);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that if I select John from the combo-box I need to fetch the value of John's salary (29000) from the XML file & display it in the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
var root = XElement.Parse(stringxml);
var empName = "John";  // This will be the string you select from combobox
var query = root
        .XPathSelectElements(string.Format("/employee[name='{0}']", empName))
        .Select(et => new
        {
            salary = (string)et.Element("salary"),
        });

var results = query.ToList();
TextBox.Text = results[0].salary;  // Set the Salary to the textbox
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select the `employee` element instead, and you can access its child elements via the indexer (`[]`):

```
foreach(XmlNode employee in doc.SelectNodes("employees/employee"))
{
    var name = employee["name"].InnerText;
    var salary = employee["salary"].InnerText;

    FeedComboBox.Items.Add($"{name} ({salary})");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fulfill my requirement. Basically, I have a string say 'Harry' so I want to fetch the salary (35000) of the employee Harry from xml file & display in the text box.